# Can't use contents of resources folder in JSP page

Tags: java, maven, jsp, web, resources

*I tried to enter an absolute path, a path relative to the resources folder, and so on, it still does not see it.*

**main.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Simple Title </title>
    <link href = "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class = "avatar" src = "images/skyrim-logo.png" alt = "avatar">
        <span class = "header-info">
            ... some info ...
        </span>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-header">
            Enter point coordinates
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`src = "images/skyrim-logo.png"` - **this line contains the problem**

[image: project structure]

[image: target structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

`<link href = "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

is relative to the `webapp` directory. However the line

`<img class = "avatar" src = "images/skyrim-logo.png" alt = "avatar">`

points to a directory which is not part of the `webapp` directory structure and therefor is not visible to the JSP page.

You need to move both the `fonts` and `images` directories into the `webapp` directory.